# Trying to get button to play Next Video button using Javascript functionality

Tags: javascript, html, button, video

I coded an HTML page with a list of videos and a featured video at the top. Next to the featured video, I also have a "Play Next" button. I added code to play the video when the thumbnail is clicked. I will change the thumbnail videos to images afterwards. Anyway, The part I could not figure out is that when the user clicks the "Play Next Video" button, the next video on the list would show as the featured video. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

```js
  let listVideo = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".ccc__video__thumb-inner-container .ccc__video__thumb"
  );

  let mainVideo = document.querySelector(".ccc__video__featured-vid iframe");

  let title = document.querySelector(
    ".ccc__video__featured-btn-container .ccc__video__featured-desc"
  );

  let plyNxt = document.querySelector(".ccc__video__featured-btn");

  listVideo.forEach((video) => {
    video.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      listVideo.forEach((vid) => vid.classList.remove("active"));
      video.classList.add("active");
      let iframe = video.querySelector("iframe");
      let text = video.querySelector(".ccc__video__thumb-desc").innerHTML;
      if (video.classList.contains("active")) {
        let src = iframe.getAttribute("src");
        mainVideo.src = src;
        title.innerHTML = text;
      }
    });
  });

  var i = 0;
  plyNxt.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (i >= listVideo.length - 1) i = -1;
    i++;
    return setVid();
    console.log(e);
  });

  function setVid() {
    listVideo.forEach((vix) => {
      if (vix.classList.contains("active")) {
        let src = iframe.getAttribute("src");
        mainVideo.src = src;
        title.innerHTML = text;
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
  <body class="home">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!--main-->
      <main id="main-content" class="main">
        <!--CCC container-->
        <div class="ccc__container">
          <section class="ccc__video__container">
            <div class="ccc__video__featured">
              <div class="ccc__video__featured-vid">
                <iframe
                  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VVAi12G7dTk"
                  title="YouTube video player"
                  frameborder="0"
                  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                  allowfullscreen
                ></iframe>
                <!-- <img src="images/featured-video-img.jpg" alt="Caregivers, you are strong." class="ccc__featured__video-img"> -->
              </div>
              <!--ccc__video__featured-vid ends-->
              <div class="ccc__video__featured-btn-container">
                <div class="ccc__video__featured-logo-container">
                  <h1>My videos</h1>
                </div>
                <!--ccc__video__featured-logo-container ends -->
                <span class="ccc__video__featured-desc"> Video 1 </span>
                <button class="ccc__video__featured-btn">NEXT VIDEO</button>
                <!-- <button class="ccc__video__featured-btn" onclick="next()">NEXT VIDEO</button> -->
              </div>
              <!-- ccc__video__featured-btn-container ends-->
            </div>
            <!-- ccc__video__featured" ends-->

            <div class="ccc__video__thumb-container">
              <div class="ccc__video__thumb-container-bg-overlay"></div>
              <div class="ccc__video__thumb-container-bg"></div>

              <div class="ccc__video__thumb-container-inner">
                <span class="ccc__video__thumb-header">RECENT UPLOADS</span>
                <div class="ccc__video__thumb-inner-container">
                  <div class="ccc__video__thumb">
                    <iframe
                      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VVAi12G7dTk"
                      title="YouTube video player"
                      frameborder="0"
                      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                      allowfullscreen
                    ></iframe>
                    <!-- <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb-img.jpg" alt="Video 1" class="ccc__video__thumb-img"></a> -->
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-desc"> Video 1 </span>
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-date">07/31/2023</span>
                    <button class="ccc__video__thumb-play">PLAY VIDEO</button>
                  </div>
                  <!--ccc__video__thumb ends-->

                  <div class="ccc__video__thumb">
                    <iframe
                      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NDYJhcfXvms"
                      title="YouTube video player"
                      frameborder="0"
                      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                      allowfullscreen
                    ></iframe>
                    <!-- <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb-img2.jpg" alt="Video 2" class="ccc__video__thumb-img"></a> -->
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-desc"> Video 2 </span>
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-date">07/31/2023</span>
                    <button class="ccc__video__thumb-play">PLAY VIDEO</button>
                  </div>
                  <!--ccc__video__thumb ends-->

                  <div class="ccc__video__thumb">
                    <iframe
                      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5Pr9nNBlKcQ"
                      title="YouTube video player"
                      frameborder="0"
                      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                      allowfullscreen
                    ></iframe>
                    <!-- <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb-img3.jpg" alt="Video 3" class="ccc__video__thumb-img"></a> -->
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-desc"> Video 3 </span>
                    <span class="ccc__video__thumb-date">07/31/2023</span>
                    <button class="ccc__video__thumb-play">PLAY VIDEO</button>
                  </div>
                  <!--ccc__video__thumb ends-->
                </div>
                <!--ccc__video__thumb-inner-container ends-->
              </div>
              <!--ccc__video__thumb-container-inner ends-->
            </div>
            <!--ccc__video__thumb-container ends-->
          </section>
        </div>
        <!--CCC container ends-->
      </main>
      <!--main ends-->
    </div>
  </body>
```